# Sharepoint 2010, not able to add new visual studio webpart

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, visual-studio

I was working in project creating new visual webpart, but suddenly 
when I create new visual webpart (basic just with a label )and try to deploy it I have the following error :

`Error occurred in deployment step 'Add Solution': The process cannot access the file 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\ch-aaa-dev80\web.config' because it is being used by another process`
 I made iis reste not working
any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to do the following :

- Make sure that there are no Multiple deployments from other users at the same time and on the same server.
- Make sure that the web config file is not opened or used by any program at any place.
- Close all running instance for Visual Studio.
- Restart Sharepoint Timer Service. (Run > Service > Sharepoint Timer Service > Restart)
- Restart IIS.

Comment: Hi @M.Qassas I m the only one working on the server, and the web.config is closed. I was working on the solution adding Webpart and deploying without any problem, but I don't know how when I add new Webpart with just label to test it , it show me this message and now nothing is working, I create new project with empty webpart. same error message ...

Comment: in CA I have this message : Last Operation Details: xxxxx : http://xxx/ : Portal : Error: The web.config could not be saved on this IIS Web Site: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\xxx\web.config. 
The process cannot access the file 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\xxx\web.config' because it is being used by another process.

Comment: PS : the old solutions still works when I deploy